# Using Urlllib2.urlopen fails for binary data?

Tags: python, download, urllib2

I'm using python to programatically download a zip file from a web server. Using a web browser, it's fine. I've written this (partial) script;

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, data, 10)
the_page = response.read()
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.write(the_page)
f.close()
```

The request succeeds and I get data. The problem is that the file I'm downloading -- a zip file -- doesn't work; the file appears to be corrupt. It seems to be the right sort of length, and looked at in text editor seems to look like a zip file content. Here are the headers from the download;

Content-Length: 9891
Content-Disposition: Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="TrunkBackup_20101230.zip"
Date: Wed, 30 Dec 2009 12:22:08 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes

When I check the length of the response, it is correct at 9891. I suspect what's happening is that when I call `response.read()` the result is a string with carriage returned 'helpfully' normalized (say, `\r` to `\n`). when I write the file, the binary data is slightly wrong, and the zip file is corrupt.

My problem is (A) I'm not sure if I'm right, and (B) if I am right, how to I save the binary data itself?

Comment: Does it work when you open file in binary mode (`open(filename, 'wb')`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try opening the file in binary mode:

```
 f = open(filename, 'wb')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [urlretrieve function](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) for downloading raw binary files.

Comment: I had problems with urlretrieve -- my app just stopped. Dunno why.

Comment: That's curious... I think urlretrieve(url, targetpath) works fine for files (and is probably pretty faster than the "url->string->file" way). Maybe you could show me your code.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is running into the same error even with the write-mode set to "wb" make sure you call either "f.flush()" or "f.close()" before attempting to work with the file, otherwise it may not be completely written.